# Can I frenzy after enraging or do I have to frenzy when I begin my rage?

Tags: dnd-5e, rage

For reference Frenzy says:

> you can go into a frenzy when you rage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only choose to begin a Frenzy when you begin a Rage.

The effect "you can go into a frenzy" is contingent on the condition "when you rage", not "when you are raging" or "at any time during your rage".